# Material UI select dropdown arrow keys navigation not working

Tags: select, search, material-ui

I added a textfield inside mui multiple select component , now keyboard arrow up and down list navigation is not  working instead,on arrow onkeydown it focuses on the div itself (scrolling on arrow keydown).
Any help is appreciated (AutoComplete is not an option)

Have tried adding autoFocus on MenuItem itself , but that starts from the last list

```
  import * as React from "react";
  import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
  import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
  import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField"; 
  import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
  import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

  const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
  const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
  const MenuProps = {
      PaperProps: {
      style: {
       maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250
      }
      } 
      };

     const names = [
     "Oliver Hansen",
     "Van Henry",
     "April Tucker",
     "Ralph Hubbard",
     "Omar Alexander",
     "Carlos Abbott",
     "Miriam Wagner",
     "Bradley Wilkerson",
     "Virginia Andrews",
    "Kelly Snyder"
    ];

    function getStyles(name: string, personName: string[], theme: Theme) {
     return {
    fontWeight:
     personName.indexOf(name) === -1
    ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
    : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium
    };
    }

    export default function MultipleSelect() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
    const {
    target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
    // On autofill we get a stringified value.
    typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
    };

    return (
    <div>
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
    <Select
      multiple
      value={personName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.key !== "Escape") {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", margin: "20px 0px" }}>
        <TextField placeholder="type..." />
      </div>
      {names.map((name) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={name}
          value={name}
          style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
        >
          {name}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
   </FormControl>
   </div>
   );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is that the TextField element is a child of the Select element and is intercepting the keydown events that would normally be used to navigate the list of options. One way to fix this would be to use the `onKeyDown` prop on the TextField element to prevent it from intercepting the keydown events. Instead of calling `e.stopPropagation()`, you can call `e.preventDefault()` which will prevent the event from being handled by the TextField element and allow it to be handled by the Select element.

```
  <TextField placeholder="type..." onKeyDown={e => e.preventDefault()}/>
```

Also to make sure that focus is on the first element in the list after the user opens the list you can use `autoFocus` prop on the first element of the list.

```
  <MenuItem
    key={names[0]}
    value={names[0]}
    style={getStyles(names[0], personName, theme)}
    autoFocus
  >
    {names[0]}
  </MenuItem>
```

This should allow the arrow keys to navigate the list as expected, while still allowing the user to type into the TextField.

Comment: thanks , but doesn't seem to work as expected same result , https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-wind-7i3jdv?file=/demo.tsx